# How to write Java 8 method reference in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a `HttpServletRequest request`, then I do

```
Optional<HttpServletRequest> optionalRequest = Optional.ofNullable(request);
String queryString = optionalRequest.map(HttpServletRequest::getQueryString);
```

Then I get this error:

```
Bad Return Type in Method Reference: cannot convert java.lang.String to U
```

Is there a workaround on this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code actually has another issue: `Optional.map(...)` returns another `Optional` containing the result. The errormessage is just a bit confusing.